# Winforms application crashing on handheld device

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I am developing a Winforms application using .Net 3.5. This application will run on desktop PCs as well as on handheld devices. I have bought "Tainell T500 POCKET PC" device. This device is running Windows XP. My compiled application works fine on PC, but gives crash on this handheld device. Error is:

```
the application failed to intialize properly (0x0000135) CLICK ON OK TO TERMINATE THE APPLICATION.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the Pocket PC have .NET 3.5 on it? Remember that 3.5 requires XP SP3.

Comment: @Ira: Should make that an answer, since installing .Net will almost certainly be the solution.

Comment: For running compiled application in "release" mode, will i need to install .net framework on that device?

Comment: Yeah I would do, only Hans has now beaten me to it. As long as it gets solved that's the main issue. The problem here could be though that if the handheld device has XP in the ROM you're (most likely) not going to be able upgrade it to SP3 and hence not able to run .NET 3.5 apps.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't paste the error message correctly.  The error code should be 0xC0000135, STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND.  Install .NET Compact Framework on the device.

Comment: Well, look on the floor, there might be a C laying around.